# Inserting 3 fields into dictionary and how to retrieve them

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to insert three fields into dictionary, so converted two fields into object type and added to the dictionary

```
int empId;
String empName;
decimal salary;

public EmployeeClass(string empName,decimal salary)
{
    this.empName = empName;
    this.salary = salary;
}

//creating dictionary object
Dictionary<int, object> employeeDictionary = new Dictionary<int, object>();

EmployeeClass emp;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee " + (i+1) + " details ");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee ID ");
    empId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Name ");
    empName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Salary of the employee ");
    salary= Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    //creating object for two fields
    emp= new  EmployeeClass(empName,salary);

    //adding to dictionary one is field and other object
    employeeDictionary.Add(empId, emp);
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the details from the dictionary:

```
var list = employeeDictionary.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();

Console.WriteLine("The Employee details according to EmpID is ");

foreach(var temp in list) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(temp + " " + employeeDictionary[temp].empName + " " + employeeDictionary[temp].salary);
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> Object does not contain definition for empName and no extension method empName accepting a first argument of type Object

How to retrieve the details from dictionary when an object type is given?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Private vs public fields

Your first problem is that your properties (`empName` and `salary`) are **private** fields of `EmployeeClass`:

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
    int empId;
    String empName;
    decimal salary;
    ...
}
```

You don't use an explicit access modifier, so per default your fields are private. Change it to this:

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
    public int empId {get; private set;}
    public String empName {get; private set;}
    public decimal salary {get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

#### 2. Use the correct type

Why are you using a `Dictionary<int,object>` if you want to store instances of `EmployeeClass`? Simply use a

```
Dictionary<int,EmployeeClass> employeeDirectory
```

So the compiler will know that the "object" in the dictionary is a `EmployeeClass` and will know it's properties. If you use `object`, the compiler has no way to know that there are those properties.

Comment: I have replaced the code with yours but its not working. When I replaced object type in dictionary to dynamic then the code is working fine and I am able to retrieve the elements

Comment: @dinesh Sorry, totally forgot the part about the `object` as type for the dictionaries values. Updated my answer